# How to set readonly the CKEditor using Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, ckeditor, readonly

I am using CKEditor 4 with knockout. I have created a custom binding handler in order to set it up. All working apartt from disabling rhe editor. In update, I can see the editor is in the list of CKEDITOR instances but the follwoing fails:

CKEDITOR.instances[element.id].setReadOnly(true);
Looking into it it seems like CKEDITOR.instances[element.id].editable() is undefined.

I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the questions by sbscribing to the click event of the checkbox that was supposed to enable.disable the editors:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isEnabled" />

this.isEnabled = ko.observable(isEnabled);
this.isEnabled.subscribe(function(val) {
    for (var instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].setReadOnly(!val);
    }
});
```